# htaccess file is not loading a file subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a curious situation: I would like to block the listing of files in a directory. Therefore I wanted to use a htaccess file. I am using an Apache webserver.

This is my configuration of my webserver:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    ServerName www.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/Files>
        Options FollowSymLinks
#        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/html/Files/admin>
       AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

In the admin directory there is a .htaccess file with this content:

```
Options -Indexes
```

I also restarted Apache without any effect. Apache runs without an error, but the directory still listens the files. The URL for the directory is https://example.com/Files/admin

Do you have any idea why it might not work? I have read that AllowOverride is required. And this seems to be the case.

Comment: If all you actually want to achieve is to prevent listing of files, then `Options -Indexes` is correct. You can simply specify that in the virtual host configuration, though, no need for all the effort with a distributed configuration file ("htaccess" and `AllowOverride`).

Comment: About why your setup does not apply the directive in that ".htaccess" file ... many potential explanations, hard to say for use without access to the system. Is that file _really_ located in the correct location? Is it _really_ called ".htaccess" (and not actually ".htaccess.txt" for example)? Is that file _really_ readable for the http server process? Is it really the name ".htaccess" that is registered in your http server for distributed configuration files (there is a configuration option to change the name)? ...

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I needed to change the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and than it worked well.